# property caching and updating

Tags: .net, caching

I'm trying to design a module to support user authentication and management in my application (C#). this module should be delivered as part of a DLL intended for infrastructure activity, so that other developers needs to use it as "third party" component. The main point here is that i'm not in charge of the UI (which depends on user permissions and session), but only supply the infrastructure to work with.

So i have created a `UserManager` singleton class, which allows actions like Login, Logout, and several more functions and events.
The UserManager class holds a property named `CurrentUser` which is of type `ApplicationUser`.

`ApplicationUser` is a class which is created with the user details (such as Fullname, User name and stuff like that), and also provides an `IsEligibleFor(Permission)` function.

I want users to get the `UserManager` instance, and communicate with the current logged on user via the `CurrentUser` property.
The ideal way would be to nullify `CurrentUser` when a Logout operation is called, and create a new `ApplicationUser` each time a user logs on. but this is problematic because a user of these classes is able to cache an instance of the `ApplicationUser`, and not notice the change.

This is why I'm thinking about moving to a solution where i have a flag in the ApplicationUser object that indicates if the object is still valid or not. but this requires checking validity in each method of the ApplicationUser, which I don't like.

I was wondering if there is some kind of solution or pattern I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is what your after. The classes would *observe* the `UserManager` class and are then subsequently notified whenever there is a change.

They could listen for specific changes, so in your scenario, they could listen for when the `ApplicationUser` object changes and they can then discard the old copy and cache the new one.

In terms of implementation, with .NET you can achieve it pretty easily using events.

Comment: This "solution" was thought of (and i will indeed let the user subscribe to an event of logoout), but i'm still looking for a solution that will take the responsibility of re-caching from the user. with your solution, i will set CurrentUser to null, but the user will still be able to mess with the old copy, not knowing that it is an old one.

Comment: Isn't it the listeners responsibility to cache the user? You could send the new user along with the event and the listeners would basically just replace their cached user object with the object sent with the event. "*with your solution, I will set CurrentUser to null, but the user will still be able to mess with the old copy*" - no they wouldn't as you would have replaced the "old" copy with the new one. I am possibly misunderstanding what your current setup is like, might be better for you to update your question with a working example.

Comment: i want the user to use this class with no need to worry about re-caching matters. I want to make sure that there is no mechanism that i'm missing. Thanks :)

Comment: I have updated about the intention of my project... i'm exposing this classes as part of a library, and someone else will use it, so i don't want to complicate the caching issue.

Comment: @YoniDor "*I want the user to use this class with no need to worry about re-caching*" - use which class specifically, the `UserManager`? If that's the case then you could do internal caching within the class itself that way whenever the access the `ApplicationUser` property it will *always* be the latest version.

Comment: i'm talking about caching of the ApplicationUser. if someone will write 'ApplicationUser user = UserManager.Instance.CurrentUser' it may end up with an old copy of CurrentUser.

Comment: What I was referring to was the class which they use to *get* the `ApplicationUser`, I understand that it's the `ApplicationUser` they want to cache. Wouldn't you just deal with the caching internally in the `UserManager`? If the user takes a local copy of `ApplicationUser` then you have no control over it and have no way of updating it.